# Regex to find specific letter before a condition Python

Tags: python, regex

I just want to find all characters (other than A) which are followed by triple A, i.e., have AAA to the right. I don’t want to include the triple A in the output and just want the character immediately preceding AAA

```
result = []

s = 'ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD'

pattern = "r'(\w[BF])(?!AAA)'"
for item in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    result.append(item.group())
  
print(result)
```

I used this pattern r'(\w[BF])(?!AAA)' but didn't worked

I just need find this letters in []

```
'ACAABAA[C]AAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDA[F]AAAC[B]AAAFASD'
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example, you want to match a single character at the left of tripple A. Using `\w[BF]` matches at least 2 characters being 1 word character followed by either `B` or `F`

The negative lookahead asserts that what is directly to the right is not tripple A, but you want the opposite.

You can match a single B-Z and assert what is directly to the right is AAA

```
[B-Z](?=AAA)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/smalfb/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FH14Fo)

```
import re
result = []

s = 'ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD'
pattern = r'[B-Z](?=AAA)'

for item in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    result.append(item.group())

print(result)
```

Output

```
['C', 'F', 'B']
```

---

You could also use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import re

s = 'ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD'
pattern = r'[B-Z](?=AAA)'
result = re.findall(pattern, s)

print(result)
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/VDxNs0)

Answer (score 2):

`[^A](?=A{3})`
Here I use positive lookahead.

Comment: Just wanted to notice that `(?=A{3})` will take less steps than `(?=AAA)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem's solution:

```
 pattern = "([B-Z]{1})(A{3})"
 for item in re.finditer(pattern, s):
     result.append(item.group(1))
```